# Can I use spine on android without libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

i am trying to use spine on a non-game app, can I do this without libgdx? and are there any other ways to use the bone animation on my app without game engine?

Comment: Your question is too broad and since you provide no input whatsoever is unlikely to get answered...

Comment: You can use Spriter for your app. https://github.com/Trixt0r/spriter

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are other Android runtimes for Spine. Check here [Runtimes](http://esotericsoftware.com/spine-runtimes)

I have used Pixijs and it worked well for my non-game Spine Android native app.
[Pixijs](https://pixijs.io/examples/#/plugin-spine/dragon.js)